# Cannot update AAD App Registration in B2C Tenant after first user logs in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-cli

I am posting this question in the style of question and answer.

I recently ran into an issue where I could not add Reply Urls to an Azure AD App Registration, which was registered in a B2C Tenant.

I had been happily updating the Reply Urls using automation using the `az ad app update --id $appIdentifier --add replyUrls "https://<a-valid-dns-zone-record>` command.

However, once you use your App Registration from a B2C tenant to perform the first login, the command above stops working. You CAN carry on using the portal to add new Reply Urls, but that isnt any good for automation!

I had googled and searched stackoverflow for answers but found none. I raised a Premier Support ticket with Microsoft, and a Github issue on the Azure CLI tool.

I got a workaournd for the problem from my [Github Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14090)

Which I will detail in my answer

Comment: "I raised a Premier Support ticket with Microsoft, and a Github issue on the Azure CLI tool.

I got a workaournd for the problem from my Github Issue"
+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `az rest` command and use it to call Graph API directly. Here is a PowerShell script I use in an Azure DevOps yaml pipeline.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$servicePrincipalId,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$servicePrincipalPassword,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$servicePrincipalTenantId,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$newReplyUrl,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$appRegIdentifier
)

Write-Host "Logging in as B2C Tenant Service Principal"
$null = az login --service-principal -u $servicePrincipalId -p $servicePrincipalPassword -t $servicePrincipalTenantId --allow-no-subscriptions

# Load some JSON/Text file helpers...
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\Json-Helpers.psm1

Write-Host "Adding $newReplyUrl if required..."

$appRegObjectId = az ad app show --id $appRegIdentifier --query 'objectId'
$graphAppRegUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$appRegObjectId"

$appJson = az rest --method GET --uri $graphAppRegUri
$app = $appJson | ConvertFrom-Json

if ($app.web.redirectUris.Contains($newReplyUrl)) {
    # ReplyUrl exists, no-op
    Write-Host "Reply Url already exists, no action required..."
    Exit 0
}

$patchApp = @{ web = @{ redirectUris = @() } }

ForEach ($url in $app.web.redirectUris) {
    $patchApp["web"].redirectUris += $url
}

$patchApp["web"].redirectUris += $newReplyUrl

$tempFile = ".\patchAppTemp-$([System.Guid]::NewGuid()).json"

try {
    $patchApp | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 | Format-Json -Minify | Set-Content -Path $tempFile -Encoding UTF8  -NoNewline

    # Update `redirectUris` for `web` property
    Write-Host "Calling Graph API to update Reply Urls"
    az rest --method patch --uri $graphAppRegUri --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --body=@$tempFile
    Write-Host "Successfully added $newReplyUrl to App Registration $appRegIdentifier"
}
finally {
    if (Test-Path $tempFile) {
        Remove-Item -Path $tempFile
    }
}
```

And for completeness, here is the Json-Helpers.psm1 PowerShell module:

```
function Get-Encoding
{
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [Alias('FullName')]
    [string]
    $Path
  )

  process 
  {
    $bom = New-Object -TypeName System.Byte[](4)
        
    $file = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($Path, 'Open', 'Read')
    
    $null = $file.Read($bom,0,4)
    $file.Close()
    $file.Dispose()
    
    $enc = 'Ascii'
    if ($bom[0] -eq 0x2b -and $bom[1] -eq 0x2f -and $bom[2] -eq 0x76) 
      { $enc =  'Utf7' }

    if ($bom[0] -eq 0xff -and $bom[1] -eq 0xfe) 
      { $enc =  'Unicode' }

    if ($bom[0] -eq 0xfe -and $bom[1] -eq 0xff) 
      { $enc =  'Bigendianunicode' }

    if ($bom[0] -eq 0x00 -and $bom[1] -eq 0x00 -and $bom[2] -eq 0xfe -and $bom[3] -eq 0xff) 
      { $enc =  'Utf32'}

    if ($bom[0] -eq 0xef -and $bom[1] -eq 0xbb -and $bom[2] -eq 0xbf) 
      { $enc =  'Utf8'}
        
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Encoding = $enc
      Path = $Path
    }
  }
}

function Format-Json {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Prettifies JSON output.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Reformats a JSON string so the output looks better than what ConvertTo-Json outputs.
    .PARAMETER Json
        Required: [string] The JSON text to prettify.
    .PARAMETER Minify
        Optional: Returns the json string compressed.
    .PARAMETER Indentation
        Optional: The number of spaces (1..1024) to use for indentation. Defaults to 4.
    .PARAMETER AsArray
        Optional: If set, the output will be in the form of a string array, otherwise a single string is output.
    .EXAMPLE
        $json | ConvertTo-Json  | Format-Json -Indentation 2
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Prettify')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$Json,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Minify')]
        [switch]$Minify,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Prettify')]
        [ValidateRange(1, 1024)]
        [int]$Indentation = 4,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Prettify')]
        [switch]$AsArray
    )

    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Minify') {
        return ($Json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress
    }

    # If the input JSON text has been created with ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    # then we first need to reconvert it without compression
    if ($Json -notmatch '\r?\n') {
        $Json = ($Json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
    }

    $indent = 0
    $regexUnlessQuoted = '(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)'

    $result = $Json -split '\r?\n' |
        ForEach-Object {
            # If the line contains a ] or } character, 
            # we need to decrement the indentation level unless it is inside quotes.
            if ($_ -match "[}\]]$regexUnlessQuoted") {
                $indent = [Math]::Max($indent - $Indentation, 0)
            }

            # Replace all colon-space combinations by ": " unless it is inside quotes.
            $line = (' ' * $indent) + ($_.TrimStart() -replace ":\s+$regexUnlessQuoted", ': ')

            # If the line contains a [ or { character, 
            # we need to increment the indentation level unless it is inside quotes.
            if ($_ -match "[\{\[]$regexUnlessQuoted") {
                $indent += $Indentation
            }

            $line
        }

    if ($AsArray) { return $result }
    return $result -Join [Environment]::NewLine
}
```

The key line is

```
az rest --method patch --uri $graphAppRegUri --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --body=@$tempFile
```

Which calls the Graph API, passing the Json content of your dynamically created temporary file. One small downside to doing it this way is that you take the current URLs, add your new one, and patch the whole list, rather than just adding the one you wanted. As the list grows, the content of the patch could get large too.

But as things stand today, this is the best way to get around the problem that I found.

Comment: I assume you need permission "Application.ReadWrite.All" for Azure AD B2C, but how do you create the principal that can access Azure AD B2C?

Comment: You can use `az ad sp create-for-rbac` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_sp_create_for_rbac. You may have to do you az login with --allow-no-subscriptions to login to a B2C tenant without an associated resource subscription.

Comment: You can also create a "Management App" - an App Registration that you can grant API permissions to and use the App Reg client as an sp in your automation code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga

Comment: We have the Azure AD B2C on another subscription than the main AD, so still do not see how that `create-for-rbac` would work, but yes the management app in B2C is a good approach once I could figure out how do I use the `az login` to access it. I also posted answer below, that should leave less gaps and have more concise code. But thanks a lot. The azure B2C doc seems to leave lots of gaps and had not come across how you combine the Azure CLI with Graph Rest API, so was really confused about that too before finding this.

Answer (score 0):

While Ian had a very good answer and would not have been able to get started without it, it also seems bit too complex. With patch command you do not need to write all the json gotten from the GET call, but only the part you want to update.

```
$myTestServiceUri = "https://my-test-url.com"
$myObjectId = "<OBJECT_ID_GUID_HERE>"
$graphAppRegUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$myObjectId"
az rest --method GET --uri $graphAppRegUri
$newUriArr = ((az rest --method GET --uri $graphAppRegUri | ConvertFrom-Json).spa.redirectUris + $myTestServiceUri)
(@{spa=@{redirectUris=$newUriArr}} | ConvertTo-Json) | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8  -NoNewlin -Path tmp-redirectUris.json
az rest --method PATCH --uri $graphAppRegUri --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --body=@tmp-redirectUris.json
```

Also good to do login before running this to test locally (had to use no subscription as Azure AD B2C tenant has got no subscription at least in my case):

```
az login --tenant <TENANT_NAME_HERE>.onmicrosoft.com --allow-no-subscriptions
```

When logging in with automated setup, one needs to use Azure B2C application configured with correct access rights and client secret (see instructions from [Azure B2C docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga#microsoft-graph-api-interaction-modes)):

```
az login --service-principal --username APP_ID --password SP1_PASSWORD --tenant TENANT_ID
```

From the [Microsoft Graph REST API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#permissions) one can also see the required permissions for the command and can configure those to B2C application. So you will need `Application.ReadWrite.All` if you are going to manage all your Applications with the same "service principal". If only this one application, use `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`.